# Convert postgres array in csv dump to vector

Tags: r, postgresql

postgres arrays in csv dump looks like this {1,2,3}
values inside curly braces.

So having table csv dump might look like this,

```
name      numbers
----     -------
john     {1,2,3}
me       {5,6}
```

How do I convert the numbers column to vector?

```
{1,2,3} -->c(1,2,3)
{5,6}  ->c(5,6}
```

Comment: `strsplit` might be helpful here.

Comment: Looks like a typo there? `->c(5,6}`

Comment: It may be easier to connect from R to postgres DB directly. It may even be easier to start a local pg instance, import csv and read all the data from it. This way you are guarantied to receive a correct data set from csv file.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the string representation in the dump, use [`array_to_string()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) in a subquery and concatenate the decorators:

```
COPY (SELECT name, 'c(' || array_to_string(numbers, ',') || ')' AS numbers
      FROM tbl) TO '/path/to/target.sql';
```

Comment: Nice one. I'm also looking for a general method in R to read once csv is already made.

Answer (score 1):

Read the data in eliminating the dashed row by setting the comment character to `"-"`, remove the brackets and split the numbers giving a list, assign the names to each list component giving `L` and use `stack` to get long form.  Finally set it up as a data frame and convert the numbers to numeric. No packages are used.

```
Lines <- "name      numbers
----     -------
john     {1,2,3}
me       {5,6}"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, comment = "-", as.is = TRUE)
L <- setNames(strsplit(gsub("[{}]", "", DF$numbers), ","), DF$name)
with(stack(L), data.frame(name = ind, number = as.numeric(values)))
```

giving:

```
  name number
1 john      1
2 john      2
3 john      3
4   me      5
5   me      6
```

If the `name` column should not be a factor replace the last line with:

```
with(stack(L), 
 data.frame(name = format(ind), number = as.numeric(values), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```